# Any injective function from a set to a proper subset is also surjective

Tags: functions

Let $X$ be a set, let $Y$ be a proper subset of $X$, let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be an injective function. Is it true that $f$ is also surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, let $X=\mathbb{Z}$ and $Y=2\mathbb{Z}=\{2n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be given by $f(k)=4k$. This is injective but misses, for instance $2\in Y$ and so isn't surjective.

I should add, an infinite set needed to be chosen for $X$ because there exist no injective functions from a finite set to a proper subset. Similarly, $Y$ needed to be an infinite subset of $X$ (and of the same cardinality).

Answer (score 1):

Another example is the map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ with $x \mapsto e^x$. It misses $(-\infty,0)$.